# Add sound to animation preview

Tags: animation, 3d-view, workflow

I want to make an animation in time to a song so when I hit play on the timeline I need to be able to hear the song so I can finely tune the animations to start and end at the right time.

Is it possible to have sound play on an animation while it is playing in the 3d viewport before it has been rendered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get 3D Sound you could add a **Speaker** to the scene

[image]

and choose the sound file in the **Properties** window

[image]

You can adjust the playback time in the **NLA** editor:

[image]

Or as another variant you could just use the **Video Sequence Editor** and add a sound file there. This will be plain playback with no positional audio.

[image]

The synchronization of audio and video/viewport playback can be set in the timeline. AV-sync will drop frames in the viewport if the scene is too heavy, so the timing will still be correct.

[image]